ModelActor and "Publishing background changes from background threads is not allowed" warning
I think my understanding of ModelActor is wrong...
I thought ModelActors are used to perform database actions that we don't want to run on the main thread and lock up the UI.
Are there any specific conditions that I need to be thinking about when trying to save a SwiftData object to the database?
I am getting the warning "Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates." even though I am not doing any UI related activity in the ModelActor. All I am doing is a bunch of SwiftData model updates and try modelContext.save() Changing this line to MainActor.run{try modelContainer.mainContext.save()} works fine but the issue is that it runs on the main thread which I dont want to do.
I tried creating a simple example, but that works fine without the message!! The code is huge and much of it is not under my control unfortunately!!
I am sure I am missing something and I am unable to figure it out. Any pointers?? Has anyone come across this scenario with a modelActor?
Thanks for your help!

Note that the warning might come from some code outside of the ModelActor code but that is executed within the same task as where you call the ModelActor function.

ModelActor should be completely separate from the UI

I found the reason for the warning. The explanation is posted in this forum : https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/765997
The issue started when I was observing the notifications from the changes to the SwiftData object and trying to save an object in a different thread started giving me the warning
